# How can I print out / visualize the Word2Vec text clustered with k-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, word2vec

I am trying to perform unsupervised learning of text data using word2vec and clustering. I have trained the model and after clustering it with K-means, I want to be able to print out the clusters as text. Visualizing the data with a regular plot or T-SNE doesn't seem informative.
My goal is to print out the clusters with text, see whether it's clustered properly and then assign categories to chunks of text based on each cluster label.

```
model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8)
kmeans.fit(X)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(X)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='black', s=200, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The plot doesn't give much information, either because of multidimensionality or the clustering didn't achieve proper results.

If I print the data with labels as it is now, it shows columns with word vectors and the label column.

```
y_new = y_kmeans.reshape(80440, 1)
with_labels = np.hstack((X, y_new))
print(with_labels)
```

I would like to be able to print out the word vectors as text instead of their numeric values and see what's going on there before trying to assign any categories to the text.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a dendrogram on it's side with text as labels. Something like this:

[image: Sample dendrogram]